# SetPixelFormat is not creating an alpha channel for OpenGL

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

I've been able to do this before, and I don't know what changed between two weeks ago and the last windows update, but for some reason `SetPixelFormat` isn't creating an alpha channel.

gDebugger shows that the window's back buffer only has 3 channels.

White+0 alpha renders as white.

So there is something inherently wrong with what I was doing, or an update broke it.

The code below should be paste-able into an empty VS project.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <dwmapi.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"dwmapi.lib")

HWND hWnd = 0;
HDC hDC = 0;
HGLRC hRC = 0;
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY WinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow
    )
{   
    WNDCLASSEX wcex = {0};

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = TEXT("why_class");

    RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
    // no errors

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
            NULL,
            TEXT("why_class"),
            TEXT("why_window"),
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
            128,128,
            256,256,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            hInstance,
            NULL
        );
    // no errors

    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = {0};
    pfd.nSize = sizeof(pfd);
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW|
        PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL|
        PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER|
        PFD_SUPPORT_COMPOSITION;
    pfd.cColorBits = 32;
    pfd.cAlphaBits = 8;     // need an alpha channel
    pfd.cDepthBits = 24;
    pfd.cStencilBits = 8;

    hDC = GetDC(hWnd);
    int i = ChoosePixelFormat(hDC,&pfd);
    SetPixelFormat(hDC,i,&pfd);
    // no errors

    hRC = wglCreateContext(hDC);
    // no errors

    wglMakeCurrent(hDC,hRC);
    // no errors

    // EDIT: Turn on alpha testing (which actually won't
    // fix the clear color problem below)
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    // EDIT: Regardless of whether or not GL_BLEND is enabled,
    // a clear color with an alpha of 0 should (or did at one time)
    // make this window transparent

    glClearColor(
        0,0,0,  // if this is (1,1,1), the window renders
                // solid white regardless of the alpha
        0   // changing the alpha here has some effect
        );

    DWM_BLURBEHIND bb = {0};
    bb.dwFlags = DWM_BB_ENABLE|DWM_BB_TRANSITIONONMAXIMIZED;
    bb.fEnable = TRUE;
    bb.fTransitionOnMaximized = TRUE;
    DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow(hWnd,&bb);
    // no errors

    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    // no errors

    MSG msg = {0};
    while(true){
        GetMessage(&msg,NULL,NULL,NULL);
        if(msg.message == WM_QUIT){
            return (int)msg.wParam;
        }
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        // this vertex should be transparent,
        // as it was when I last built this test
        //
        // it renders as white
        glColor4f(1,1,1,0);
        glVertex2f(0,0);
        glColor4f(0,1,1,1);
        glVertex2f(1,0);
        glColor4f(1,0,1,1);
        glVertex2f(0,1);
        glEnd();

        SwapBuffers(hDC);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{   
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        }return 0;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: "White+0 alpha renders as white." Of course it renders white; you didn't turn on blending. Alpha doesn't mean "transparent". It means whatever you want it to mean. So if you want alpha to mean "transparent", you have to _make_ it mean "transparent". Generally via the use of a blend mode.

Comment: I honestly didn't notice alpha testing wasn't on here... I wish I had screenshots of it working before, but I guess I was working with a bug that allowed it to render directly to the framebuffer that way. I enabled alpha testing to see if that would work, however it did not affect the vertex indicated (it still renders white, just now only slight transparent). However the question I have is why my window suddenly doesn't have an alpha channel -- or why everything I render looks as though windows is expecting premultiplied alpha.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I think the OP means the alpha channel to be used for window composition, i.e. transparent windows. (PFD_SUPPORT_COMPOSITION flag set). There's little influence upon how the compositor treats the alpha channel, but usually it's assumed being opacity. Some compositors assume pre-multiplied alpha, other's don't. See https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/tree/master/samples/OpenGL/x11argb_opengl_glsl for a equivalent example for  X11/GLX.

Answer (score 0):

You typically can't get a frame buffer that has both 32bits of color and 8 bits of alpha.

I have not tried your code, but would suggest to switch the color bits to 24.

```
pfd.cColorBits = 24;
pfd.cAlphaBits = 8;
```

Comment: In MSDN's documentation page on `PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR`, under `cAlphaBits`, it says: "Specifies the number of alpha bitplanes in each RGBA color buffer. Alpha bitplanes are not supported."  Does that mean you can't get an alpha channel?

Comment: @JWWalker: I have no idea what that bit of the doc means.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I still end up with a 24-bit color buffer without alpha, even if I just leave the whole thing 0 (except the flags, version, and size). The only difference being that if I specify any number for cAlphaBits, the window actually does render transparently (with the asinine premultiplied alpha nonsense), I just don't have access to the alpha channel.

Comment: @i_photon: how do you check what you get ? It can't be transparent if it does not have an alpha channel, no ?

Comment: I use `GetPixelFormat` and `DescribePixelFormat`, as well as gDebugger (which probably does the same thing at some point). As far as the window transparency: I think windows reserves a separate, inaccessible (as far as I know) alpha image for the DWM and layered windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use blending, just call:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Although for this to work, you do have to have something behind your triangle to blend with (the black background doesn't count!)

Comment: The black background counts as well. You can render semi-transparent white square and perfectly see it.